# Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key) in live site. But works in locally

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, build

My React App is running well locally. But on live site it shows this error and loads nothing.

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
    at Ut (main.d108a90a.js:2:403619)
    at Bt (main.d108a90a.js:2:403758)
    at main.d108a90a.js:2:514892
    at e.instanceFactory (main.d108a90a.js:2:515499)
    at e.value (main.d108a90a.js:2:385751)
    at e.value (main.d108a90a.js:2:384861)
    at qt (main.d108a90a.js:2:404273)
    at main.d108a90a.js:2:524925
    at main.d108a90a.js:2:524981
    at main.d108a90a.js:2:80
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, My env vars are declared as:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=xxxxxx
REACT_APP_authDomain=xxxx
/....
```

here, the I should write `REACT_APP_apikey` instead of `REACT_APP_API_KEY`.
I edited this and worked. :)